# Windows 7 screen resolution

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have an HP110 netbook with Intel 945 Express graphics chipset.  The basic screen resolution is 1024 x 576.  When this machine had Windows XP installed, you could go into the graphics properties, uncheck the 'Monitor Settings/Hide modes that this monitor cannot display' checkbox and select, for instance, 1024x768.  This gave you a scrolling viewport that was larger than the actual screen.

I installed Windows 7 and the checkbox is greyed out, so I cannot select 1024x768.  Does anyone know how to get this checkbox activated, or to get a viewport larger than the screen? Is it a property of the Win7 driver, or is there perhaps a registry entry I can modify?

I have installed the current Win7 driver from Intel's site.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need a Windows 7 driver for your graphics card.

See what the Device Manager says?  A question mark or nothing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the driver is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use this free utility: [Display Changer](http://www.12noon.com/displaychanger.htm)
It has a command line mode which allows you to use switches to override things like checking for supported resolution.
I also use this when I have my laptop on the desk and a large TFT next to it higher up, to get the mouse to move smoothly from one to the other in the overlapping region (ie so the top of the laptop screen is offset to be about halfway down the TFT)

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but it didn't work.  According to the Display Changer site, 'if you can't use the built-in Windows 7 Control Panel to select the resolution you want, DC won't be able to do it either'.  Guess I'll have to hope for an updated driver.

Answer (score 0):

Get the actual Intel 945 Express graphics driver for windows 7.  It 'might' be something with windows installing a 'good' match driver.  It'll work, but not as good as it can.  Win7 has been better with finding drivers, but still gets it wrong once and a while.

Comment: Thanks, but that was the first thing I did.