# Can't Run 1024x768 in Wipro Notebook (Grapics Driver Issue)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, drivers, resolution

I have an [wipro notebook 7f381x](https://www.google.com/search?q=wipro%20notebook%207f381x&sxsrf=ALeKk0390JVRVKzEGvrfPDtkCURMzeENrQ:1626889866199&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZwsCE3fTxAhUHQH0KHcu2AFEQ_AUoAXoECAEQAw&biw=1024&bih=457) which is Pretty old and i can't run `1024x768` Screen Resolution , What i Have :

I have an 1024x768 Digital Flat Panel ,
Chip type :`Intel GMA 950`(*Refered from Advanced Settings in Display Properties in Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit*)
Dac Type:`Internal`
**Adapter String**:**`Mobile Intel 945 Express Chipset Family`**
Bios Information: Intel Video Bios
Grapic Memory:250 mb
Dedicated Video Memory:0;
System Video Memory: 64 MiB

Ram : 1Gib DDr2
Processor:Intel Atom N270

Right  Now i Have Installed Drivers from [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29369/Intel-Graphics-Media-Accelerator-Driver-for-Windows-7-exe-)
First From Starting :

My PC came with windows 7 Which was Running Well in 1024x768 Resolution but when windows 7 Support Ended I Moved to Windows 10 by Using Official Media Creation tool by Microsoft (TM),In Windows 10 i kept up Using as Usual in 1024x768  Res. but My PC Lags and i Moved to windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit (*Even after end of life*) but Don't Remember Screen Resolution ,then i Moved to
Lubuntu 18.4 LTS and still using 1024x768 Screen Resolution and i moved back to windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit by Pirating from softlay.com then i  Moved to Different OS but Not With Problem But 3 Days Before i Wanna Move Back to Windows from Ubuntu I Download Windows 8 iso Image and installed with help of WoeUsb and a pendrive of 4 gb storage but in windows 8 my resolution was  800x 600 and in system properties it was telling my **Adapter String**:**`Microsoft Basic Display`** and after using it for 1 day it automatically Changed my Res. back to  1024x768 and **Adapter String**:**`Mobile Intel 945 Express Chipset Family`** then i moved to windows 8.1 using media creation tool provided by Microsoft then , it was screen resolution to 800x 600 and in system properties it was telling my **Adapter String**:**`Microsoft Basic Display`** Now after using it for one hour i am back to Windows  7 today.....

***Clue***:*I can run MS Store  in Windows 10 but not in 8 or  8.1 because it was saying i need 1024x768 Screen Resolution*

***Help Me Because i am now at windows 7 but i need to move to an alive windows***

Thanks in Advance and feel free to edit  or Discard Question

Comment: I Know the Question is Not Clarified , but i Cannot Buy a New PC

Comment: Note : My Question is Related to Question [Here] [1]    [1] [https://superuser.com/questions/68068/windows-7-screen-resolution]  but i have tried all but didn't work and i am asking for windows 8.1